# readLine and try.kotlinlang.org

Tags: kotlin, readline

Learning a little Kotlin and using try.kotlinlang.org before installing the full IDE.  I tried the following code, but there doesn’t appear to be a prompt for me enter text:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val txt = readLine()
  if (txt != null) println("$txt")
}
```

There are no errors.  What am I missing?  Is this a limitation of try.kotlinlang.org?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the output console can take keyboard input. If you use:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val txt = args[0]
  println("$txt")
}
```

and give it a program argument of `"Bob"`, it will print that out.

Comment: Thanks David.  If the console there is truly limited, I guess I’ll have to work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("enter text:")
    val txt = readLine()
    if (txt != null) println("$txt")
}
```

position the cursor after the prompt,type anything you want and press Enter.